# ACS Rest API similar to Windows Azure Service Management REST API Reference

Tags: xml, azure, httpwebrequest, acs

I found ACS Management Service API Reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh278947.aspx.

I feel this is not as similar to Windows Azure Service Management REST API Reference. Except metadata I could not pull over the remaining information.

Any better samples explaining this.

Else is it possible to directly list out the ACS namespaces based on Subscription ID.

In deep trouble please help on...

This is how Im trying to pull the data

string hittingUri = 
"https://{0}.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/service/importFederationMetadata/importIdentityProvider";

```
       hittingUri=String.Format(hittingUri, acsnamespace);

        XmlDocument responsebody =await HelperMethods.GetXmlACSDocument(hittingUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're trying to create a new identity provider by importing the federation metadata. There is a managed library available on code.msdn.com which you can use to interact with the ACS Service management API: [ACS.Management](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385/sourcecode?fileId=71587&pathId=1385676881). Here is an example of this library which imports the federation metadata from a file:

```
        ManagementService svc = ManagementServiceHelper.CreateManagementServiceClient(); 
        using (Stream metadataFileStream = new FileStream(fedMetadataFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
        { 
            svc.ImportIdentityProviderFromStream(metadataFileStream); 
        }
```

I suggest you take a look at this library first.

Comment: I don't want to create any new namespace. I just want to pull the exsisitng information of ACS name space like Name,List of Identity providers used etc. I have gone through the library but it is bit confusing  in sampleConfiguration.cs file present in project named Common. Like Do I need to manually input ManagmentServiceIdentityKey and all the stuff.

Comment: The ACS management service uses OData and cannot be queried as a REST endpoint in the way you're attempting. ACS doesn't provide a way to query multiple namespaces programmatically, but what you can do is query each namespace's identity providers or other data if you have the management service key, as in the linked sample. The sample uses a hard-coded management key, but you could easily provide this dynamically. Obviously, though, you can only query namespaces you own as you need the key.